# Plotly in R: 3D Line Graphs - Preventing One Continuous Line

Tags: r, graph, 3d, plotly

I'm new to using Plotly in R.

I am trying to construct a 3d line graph.

I am trying to achieve a graph that looks like this:

[image]

The above is my objective and I can't seem to make it work.

When I impliment what I think the right code is, I get one continuous line (so the last value of the first series line above is connected to the first value of the second series, etc).

Here is my result (you are viewing from an angle that shows the problem of the "looping"):

[image]

My code is here:

```
fig <- plot_ly(df_cohort_master, y = ~ord_month, x = ~cohort, z = ~conversions, 
                  type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',color=~conversions) %>%
                  layout(
                    scene= list(
                      xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"),
                      yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed")))

suppressWarnings(print(fig))
```

And here is what my data looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to separate the data? The first graph likely has a fourth variable used to separate the data. (This is usually a factor field.)

Comment: I want each line to represent one cohort.

Comment: @kat if I make cohort a factor think that solves the problem?

Comment: No, that won't tell `plotly` what you want. Try adding to the `plot_ly` call: `transform = list(list(type = 'groupby', groups = ~cohort))`

Comment: @kat - I added the `transform` as you suggested inside the `plot_ly` call and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using `split` to separate into multiple traces based on your `cohort`.

Here's an example with made up data based on your post.

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

df_cohort_master <- data.frame(
  cohort = rep(1:4, times = 5),
  ord_month = rep(1:4, each = 5),
  conversions = sample(20, 20)
)

plot_ly(df_cohort_master,
        x = ~cohort, 
        y = ~ord_month, 
        z = ~conversions, 
        type = 'scatter3d', 
        mode = 'lines',
        split = ~cohort) %>%
  layout(
    title = "3D Scatter plot", 
    scene = list(
      camera = list(
        eye = list(x = 1, y = 2, z = 2)
      )
    )
  )
```

**Plot**

[image: 3d plot with multiple traces]